# Comparing Proportions of Different Measures within Same Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sampling, biostatistics

I currently have 200 observations from different (randomly sampled) participants. For each participant, I have 4 measures: MS1, MS2, MS3, MS4. Each measure is a different binary measure for a biological condition. Such that, 1 = has the condition, 0 = does not have the condition. Given this, it is highly likely that if someone has MS1=1 then MS3=1 as they are measures of the same underlying biological condition. That being said, the measures vary subtly in their methodology so they have different levels of sensitivity.

I do not know the true diagnosis of the biological condition for each observation. Only the values for MS1, MS2, MS3, MS4 (so no value where I can say, yes this person definitely has the condition).

How can I best compare the proportions of the 4 measures against each other in terms of their sensitivity or explanatory value? Similarly, is there anything else that could aid me in the analysis?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the true condition of the patients, then I don't see how you can measure sensitivity or any related quantity.

You could try combining the four measures, either through simple addition or via a factor analysis, but factor analysis of dichotomous data needs some special methods and probably won't be a lot better than adding.

By combining them you help ameliorate any errors.

You could also look at patients where the measures disagree and see if you can determine anything from other information about the patient.